# Which one is the latest stable version of Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

I am having Ubuntu 14.04LTS in my system. I am planning on downloading Hadoop for my project work. Kindly suggest me which one is the latest hadoop version which is stable and supported for various packages.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Please check this site. http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Checking this website: http://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html. Here you will find the latest hadoop release.

Current stable release is 2.7.x. Check this [link](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/).

Hope it helps :)